# Расширение функциональности IEnumerator<T>

Tags: c#, .net, framework, интерфейс

Думаю наиболее общий интерфейс доступа к набору элементов это `IEnumerable<T>` и `IEnumerator<T>`. Почти все, если не абсолютно все, контейнеры поддерживают его. Данный паттерн хорош тем, что позволяет получить доступ к абсолютно любому набору в не зависимости от его внутренней структуры хранения. Например все массивы T[], контейнеры из `System.Collections.Generic`, методы с `yield return` и т.д.

1) Однако столкнулся с необходимостью вести обработку некоторой последовательности элементов с возможностью возврата назад. Т.е. для обработки N-ого элемента возможно понадобиться получить N+m элементов. В общем случае решение данной проблемы заключается в клонировании основного итератора на N-ом элементе. Клон далее используется только для прогона до N+m элемента. Затем основной итератор продолжает работу с N-ого на котором остановился. Данное решение хорошо тем, что очень легко реализуется. Для этого достаточно реализовать метод `Clone` интерфейса `ICloneable`. Обычно это всего 1 строчка:

```
public class MyEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>, ICloneable
{
    // Во внутренних полях обычно хранится указатель на контейнер и индекс текущего элемента в нем,
    // либо указатель на элемент связанной структуры.

    // Реализация методов IEnumerable<T> ...

    public object Clone()
    {
        // Простое поверхностное копирование немногочисленных внутренних полей
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

В качестве примера класс `System.CharEnumerator` с описанием в MSDN его применения и сценария клонирования.

Данное решение очень просто в реализации, универсально и экономично.  Тем не менее на вскидку удалось найти только 2 случая его применения - энумератор в строке (вышеупомянутый `System.CharEnumerator`) и не типизированный энумератор в массиве:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    {
        // Строка имеет единый System.CharEnumerator, поддерживающий клонирование
        string str = "123";
        IEnumerator<char> enumerator = ((IEnumerable<char>)str).GetEnumerator(); // System.CharEnumerator
        ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable)enumerator; // System.CharEnumerator
        IEnumerator<char> enumerator2 = (IEnumerator<char>)cloneable.Clone(); // System.CharEnumerator
    }

    {
        // IEnumerator<T> в массивах клонирование не поддерживает
        char[] arr = new char[3];
        IEnumerator<char> enumerator = ((IEnumerable<char>)arr).GetEnumerator(); // System.SZArrayHelper.SZGenericArrayEnumerator<char>
        //ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable)enumerator; // System.InvalidCastException
    }

    {
        // IEnumerator в массивах клонирование поддерживает
        char[] arr = new char[3];
        IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)arr).GetEnumerator(); // System.Array.SZArrayEnumerator
        ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable)enumerator; // System.Array.SZArrayEnumerator
        IEnumerator enumerator2 = (IEnumerator)cloneable.Clone(); // System.Array.SZArrayEnumerator
    }

    {
        // IEnumerator от List<T> клонирование не поддерживает
        List<char> lst = new List<char>();
        IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)lst).GetEnumerator(); // System.Collections.Generic.List<char>.Enumerator
        //ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable)enumerator; // System.InvalidCastException
    }

    {
        // IEnumerator<T> от List<T> клонирование не поддерживает
        List<char> lst = new List<char>();
        IEnumerator<char> enumerator = ((IEnumerable<char>)lst).GetEnumerator(); // System.Collections.Generic.List<char>.Enumerator
        //ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable)enumerator; // System.InvalidCastException
    }

    {
        // IEnumerator<T> в yield return методе клонирование не поддерживает
        IEnumerator<char> enumerator = ((IEnumerable<char>)YieldReturnMethod()).GetEnumerator(); // tmp.Program.<YieldReturnMethod>d__1
        //ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable)enumerator; // System.InvalidCastException
    }

    {
        // IEnumerator в yield return методе клонирование не поддерживает
        IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)YieldReturnMethod()).GetEnumerator(); // tmp.Program.<YieldReturnMethod>d__1
        //ICloneable cloneable = (ICloneable)enumerator; // System.InvalidCastException
    }
}

static IEnumerable<char> YieldReturnMethod()
{
    yield return 'a';
    yield return 'b';
    yield return 'c';
}
```

Факт такой малой поддержки `ICloneable` вызывает недоумение. Получается, что почти для всего придется писать свой собственный класс реализующий `IEnumerable<T>` и 2ой класс, реализующий `IEnumerator<T>`. Вероятно наиболее общим вариантом будет предварительное получение всей последовательности, сохранения ее в своем контейнере и использовании затем своего набора классов, реализующие нужные интерфейсы. Однако такой вариант в некоторых случаях может оказаться либо неприменимым, либо очень ресурсоемким.
Хотел бы поинтересоваться, кто что об этом думает.

Comment: По поводу второй части вопроса, приведите лучше конкретный пример.

Comment: А еще лучше - оформите вторую часть вопроса отдельным вопросом

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что обычно клонирование энумератора лишено смысла.

Например, если ваши данные приходят из сети, нет смысла клонировать энумератор: вы не сможете пройти по данным два раза, не кешируя их (а это, очевидно, большой и неоправданный расход памяти).

Если ваша последовательность получена при помощи генератора (функции с `yield return`), точно так же вы не сможете склонировать данные. Хуже того, последовательность при повторном пробеге может измениться (например, если выдаваемые данные зависят от внешнего мира).

Случай, когда последовательность известна заранее, материализирована и фиксирована, известен. В этом случае у вас есть интерфейс `IList<T>`, в котором вы можете просто запомнить текущий индекс.

---

Если вам известно, на сколько нужно заглянуть вперёд, легко написать обёртку.

```
class LookaheadEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    readonly IEnumerable<T> wrapped;
    readonly int maxLookaheadSize;

    public LookaheadEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> wrapped, int maxLookaheadSize)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.maxLookaheadSize = maxLookaheadSize;
    }

    public LookaheadEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() =>
        new LookaheadEnumerator<T>(wrapped.GetEnumerator(), maxLookaheadSize);
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

class LookaheadEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>, IEnumerator
{
    List<T> lookaheadBuffer;
    readonly int maxLookaheadSize;
    readonly IEnumerator<T> wrapped;

    public LookaheadEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> wrapped, int maxLookaheadSize)
    {
        if (maxLookaheadSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("expect positive lookahead size");
        this.maxLookaheadSize = maxLookaheadSize;
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public T Current => lookaheadBuffer[0];
    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
    public void Dispose() => wrapped.Dispose();

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (lookaheadBuffer == null)
            lookaheadBuffer = new List<T>(maxLookaheadSize);
        else if (lookaheadBuffer.Count > 0)
            lookaheadBuffer.RemoveAt(0);

        while (lookaheadBuffer.Count < maxLookaheadSize)
        {
            if (!wrapped.MoveNext())
                break;
            lookaheadBuffer.Add(wrapped.Current);
        }

        return lookaheadBuffer.Count > 0;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        wrapped.Reset();
        lookaheadBuffer = null;
    }

    public bool Lookahead(int idx, out T t)
    {
        bool good = idx >= 0 && idx < lookaheadBuffer.Count;
        t = good ? lookaheadBuffer[idx] : default(T);
        return good;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var seq = new LookaheadEnumerable<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 4), 7);
using (var en = seq.GetEnumerator())
while (en.MoveNext())
{
    var value = en.Current;
    int lookehead;
    if (en.Lookahead(2, out lookehead))
        Console.WriteLine($"value: {value}, lookahead + 2: {lookehead}");
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"value: {value}, no lookahead");
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43623/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---ienumeratort).